Is asking about Neapolitan on topic?
I'm somehow new here in Italian Language.
I know Neapolitan is not Italian, but hoping to find somebody with this knowledge here, is it possible to ask about Neapolitan in this site? 

Chi tace acconsente :·)

This is an old debate.
And this is the answer we agreed upon back then:
Are questions about dialects on topic?
Of course, with new users new opinions are welcome.

Ma... non è una lingua?
